# C# linq query convert to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have some C# LINQ code and would like to convert it to vb.net. Can you help?
  Dim ProjectsPerUser As New List(Of tbProjekt)
    var currentUserId = 25;
    var prjectId = 10;

```
ProjectsPerUser = db.tbProjekt.Where(s => s.tbUserProjects
                          .Any(x => x.UserId == currentUserId)).ToList();
```

In the first case, I tried:

```
Dim ProjectsPerUser As New List(Of tbProjekt)


    var currentUserId = 25;  
    ProjectsPerUser = db.tbProjekt.Where(Function(s) s.tbUserProjects.Any(Function(x) x.UserId = currentUserId )).ToList()
```

But, I got this error:

> Late binding operations cannot be converted to expression tree

on line `s.tbUserProjects.Any`.

**full code:
(tables within context: tbProjekt and tbUserProjects)**

```
Dim dabcon As New production_TextEntitesContext
Dim ProjectsPerUsers As New List(Of tbProjekt)
Dim userSessionId As Integer = 111
ProjectsPerUsers = dabcon.tbProjekt.Where(Function(s) s.tbUserProjects.Any(Function(x) x.UserId = userSessionId)).ToList()
```

Comment: Do you have `Option Infer` on?

Comment: no what would i need it for?

Comment: For the compiler to infer the generic types used in the Linq extension methods.  Other wise you'd hsave to explicitly state them: `Function(s As Project)...`

Comment: @D Stanley i added infer to on but i still got this error as in my main post

Comment: What is you explicitly state the types (`s As Project`, `x As UserProject`)?

Comment: @D Stanley see main topic: full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98288/discussion-between-johndoe-and-d-stanley).

Answer (score 1):

Should be just a matter of:

```
ProjectsPerUser = db.tbProjekt.Where(Function(s) s.tbUserProjects.Any(Function(x) x.UserId = currentUserId)).ToList()
```